# Resource loading fail in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

Error is the profile picture in the `navbar`

**JOB DETAIL PAGE:**

[image: Navbar on Job Detail Page]

**FIND JOB PAGE:**

[image: Navbar on FindJob page]

Sometimes this error shows:
[image: Error image]

Piece of code when clicking on **Details** link on **Find Job** page:

```
<td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
    <a
      href={`/detail/${person._id}`}
      className="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900"
     >
       Details
    </a>
</td>
```

Error in **Job Detail** page:
[image: Resource loading error]

This error happens every time when I use `id` in URL parameters. Other data load perfectly. Just pictures and documents didn't load. What I should do?
I am using the MERN stack.

Comment: Show us how you're trying to load the picture in your code

Comment: `const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))` Getting data from localstorage.  `<img
                            className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                            src={data.profilepic}
                            alt=""
                          />` and send picture path in image. It loads perfectly in that pages where i didn't use "id" in url parameters.

Comment: remove the space between folder name 'Gene uploads' >>> 'Gene_uploads'

Comment: This is not a problem. uploads/1633.... so on showing the path of the image. Generate_Certificate.. is the picture name. Both are seperate things

Comment: the error clearly says that the image you requested does not exist. if you are sure that the image exists and everything works well with the saving and serving static files (image), please add the related node.js codes into the question.

Comment: to test the static file, paste the "http://localhost:3000/detail/uploads/163990407215Generate_Certificate_1633879694840" which is your image URL inside of your browser. if the image exists, it should be displayed.

Comment: @novonimo this request must send to localhost:5000/uploads/... because files are uploaded into backend server and backend server is running on localhost:5000

Comment: so why you are using localhost:300 for your images?, I think you got the problem right now

Comment: I use proxy for call to backend which is "proxy":"localhost:5000" which loads perfectly for other pages